# PHP equivalent of Perl's TIE

Tags: php

Is there an equivalent to PERL's TIE in php?  I'd like to see if a string(single word) is in a file where each line is a single word/string.  If it is, I'd like to remove the entry.  This would be very easy to do in Perl but unsure how I would do this in PHP.

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire entry/line if it contains the single word, or remove the single word from each entry/line?

Comment: Entire line, but only because I will only have one word/entry per line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you read the file will determine how you remove the entry.

**Using [`fgets`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php):**

```
$filtered = "";
$handle = fopen("/file.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
    // Read file line-by-line
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if (strpos($buffer, "replaceMe") === false)
            $filtered .= $buffer;
    }
}

fclose($handle);
```

**Using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):**

```
filterArray($value){
    return (strpos($value) === false);
}

// Read file into a string
$string   = file_get_contents('input.txt');
$array    = explode("\n", $string);
$filtered = array_filter($array, "filterArray");
```

**Using [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):**

```
function filterArray($value){
    return (strpos($value) === false);
}

// Read file into array (each line as an element)
$array    = file('input.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$filtered = array_filter($array, "filterArray");
```

**Note:** Each method assumes that you want to remove the *entire entry* if it contains a single word.

Comment: In the first method, I was inconsistent  -- I append the words into a string. To append to an array, declare `$filtered = array()` and append using `$filtered[]` instead of `$filtered .=`.